# Where to put nested resources delete for many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, resources, nested

I have Rails 4 app with nested resources and the child(session) also has a many-to-many relationship with another model (speakers).

```
 resources :parent do
   resources :child
 end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :parent
  has_and_belongs_to_many :speakers
end

class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children
end
```

I am trying to figure out which controller should have the delete/add for the relationship(speaker). I could  handle this in the SessionController#destroy but would have to handle a special case for this relationship(doesn't feel right). Currently I have a custom route to SessionController#speaker passing in a param of operation(:add, :delete).

I am keeping the records on both sides of the relationship, only remove the relationship

```
sessions.speakers.delete(speaker)
```

What do you think are the best approaches for this?

- Keep the remove relationship in SessionController in a special route
- Add to SpeakerController in a special route
- Create a new controller to handle the relationship

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveRecord**

To add or remove objects from a collection, you have the [`<<` and `.delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) ActiveRecord methods

These work using ActiveRecord objects, and can be called like this:

```
#apps/controller/posts_controller.rb
def comment
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])

    #Add
    post.comments << comment

    #Delete
    post.comments.delete(comment)
end
```

---

**Controller**

In response to your question as to which controller, I'd recommend keeping the code in the "parent" controller (in your case, `sessions`) & creating a single method to handle the process

Here's live code we created last week:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :entries do
   match ":category_id", to: :category, via: [:post, :delete], as: "category"
end

#app/controllers/entries_controller.rb 
def category
    entry = Entry.find(params[:entry_id])
    category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

    #Actions
    entry.categories << category if request.post?
    entry.categories.delete(category) if request.delete?

    #Return
    redirect_to collection_path
end
```

This allows us to call a single link with different `:method` to call different actions:

```
<%= link_to "Add Category", admin_entry_category_path("60", "20"), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the delete and <<. I like the route you created feels much better than passing an extra params, using the method for the action to be performed.